# Do you have links to any tutorials on setting up MVC on Amazon EC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, amazon-ec2

Please share links to tutorials on how to set up and run ASP.NET MVC on an Amazon EC2 virtual machine.

I know that it's possible, but I'd like to follow behind someone else that's already set it up and has it running.  It'd be great to know of a EC2 bundle that already has everything set up as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I made a screencast](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/screencast-setting-up-windows-on-amazon-ec2/) that will show you how to get Windows up and running, but it stops short of configuring IIS for MVC. However, once the instance is up and running, configuring IIS is the same as any other Windows Server 2K3 box.

Comment: Right, I think what I'm missing is that I started setting up a server last night, closed it before I went to bed and this morning it was gone.  I read something about elastic storage or something?  How do you persist the changes you make?

Comment: Server instances are not permanent. It's a completely different way of running a server. There are ways to setup persistent storage, but if you don't know why you would want that or what you're looking for, it's probably not the right setup for you.

Comment: :)  I'm just looking for guidance.  I'll read more about how to set things up.  It may well not be right for me, but I'm curious and learning.